# Jetpack Compose 2023 to stop the keyboard overlaping the screen content

Tags: android, keyboard, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Note: It's Jan 2023 and I'm learning the latest Jetpack Compose. I say this as most of the main documentation / samples and answers on here are simply out of date and just don't work in many cases.

Even the demo apps are old (even updated) and still using a lot of stuff that isn't used now (their words not mine).

I am using the last 11, 12, 13 versions of android though only as for learning.

I'm normaly a SwiftUI Developer but I am currently learning Jetpack Compose (with Material 3).

Most of it I have reasonably got to grips with but I am really struggling to stop the screen keyboard overlapping the screen content on a cell phone that has a long input form.

What I have tried (that hasn't worked):

```
a. Adding 'android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"' to the Android Manifest activity section.

b. Using the "google/accompanist" library. This I keep reading for this issue is now out of date as it is (supposedly) in the direct library.

c. Various other weird (old) fixes that no longer work either.
```

Now it appears that whatever is built in to the standard library now that does what the "google/accompanist" library did (somehow??) and (it is the way to do it now??) but I cannot find a good example.

I keep seeing a few references to "WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(...)" but none of these examples work.

I just want the page when a soft keyboard appears to scroll up the page (and out of scope here but to disappear after entering stuff or maybe some way for the user to close it).

Now note I'm using Material 3 (and this page shows fine) but this is the general layout of the page:

```
// The MainActivity.kt page is pretty standard.


@Composable
fun SomePage(...) {

    Column() {

        Text(
            text = "Some Form",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge)

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        OutlinedTextField(...)
        
        // LOTS (ish as I am purposefully being silly to prove the point) etc...


        Button(
            onClick = {
                " /* Click stuff */ "
            }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Next",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to see an answer to this as well.

Comment: I did find this but in truth it just seems messy and didn't help me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8waTylS0wUc

Comment: I will have a look.

Comment: Try to always learn from the source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlL6H-s0nF0&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers

Comment: @WilliamHumphreys, not sure if you'd still like to see an answer to this. If so, I hope that mine can help you find your way in this mess..

Answer (score 1):

The comments on the question did point me in the right direction and I'd just like to add the following answer for future people finding this page, so they don't have to dive into the different parts to much.

The base comes from the [YouTube link shared by F.Mysir](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlL6H-s0nF0), which I do recommend to watch. I'm using the following compose material3 version in my project: `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha03`.

**Step 1:**

Open your `AndroidManifest.xml`, and add the following line to your application:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

**Step 2:**

Within your `onCreate` of the `MainActivity`, just below `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`, add the following line:

`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`

**Step 3:**

Make sure your Column is scrollable:

```
Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
   ...
}
```

**Step 4:**

At the bottom of your screen (below the Button), place a spacer. This spacer will have it's padding set depending on the IME (keyboard) state. This allows the user to scroll the last button into view without closing the keyboard.

```
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.imePadding())
```

Comment: See my new comment below.

Answer (score 0):

It's the 24th of July 2023 and as Jetpack Compose is moving constantly I'm guessing this will change as it grows.

I didn't fix this how @Mathlight did above but he did do some similar things.

I will add this as an extra as I'm guessing we both did *stuff that worked so look at both answers for 'answers'.

Firstly: Open your AndroidManifest.xml, and add the following line to your application > Activity Node:

Note in my case I had multiple activity nodes (sub nodes of the application node) and I had to add it to each activity node for it to work for each activity's view / page.

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

I personally think that this is the main thing going on here that fixes the issue.

This is the code *part in my view / page (some specific to my App).

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            
            // Specific stuff to my page

        },
        
        // THIS IS THE PART I THINK MATTERS.
        content = { scaffoldPadding  ->

            // AND THIS
            Column(Modifier.padding(scaffoldPadding)) {

                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .padding(20.dp)
                        
                        // AND THIS.
                        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                    
                    
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)) {
```

Now I originally added this (I'm sure from some docs somewhere):

```
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

But when I removed it it made no difference and the scroll still worked. (Unless I'm missing something).

I hadn't come across this:

```
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.imePadding())
```

And mine still seems to work without it.

I have no padding underneath my bottom buttons. I guess this may be other things within my app so I'd just experiment using it and  then removing it.